# Is it possible to access/manipulate the constraints in a nib file from the view it's loaded into?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nib, nslayoutconstraint

Example project: http://cl.ly/1g1L3E2Z0r1c

I create a nib file and then create some views in it, which I then load into another view controller. In the view that I bring in, it's a subclass of UIView where I have outlets set up for its properties. I have one specifically for its constraint from distance from the top.

But when I try to access it in code (like as follows), I can't, it states it's null:

```
self.tutorialScreen3.textLabelDistanceFromTop.constant += 150.0;
NSLog(@"%@", self.tutorialScreen3.textLabelDistanceFromTop);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
```

you're loading the last view from your `View.xib` file, and it's view 3, but you're property `textLabelDistanceFromTop` is not connected with this view, but with view 2.

You just need to make in view 3 the same constraints you made in view 2 and to connect the textLabelDistanceFromTop property with appropriate constraint in view 3, and it wan't be nil any more.

I already did this in your project, so you can download it from this location http://goo.gl/gGvIkn